# Reuse same database tables in different repositories (repositories overlap on the data they access)

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Suppose I have database tables `Customer`, `Order`, `Item`. I have `OrderRepository` that accesses, directly with SQL/my ORM, *both* the Order and Items table. E.g. I could have a method, `getItems` on the `OrderRespositry` that returns all items of that order.

Suppose I now also create `ItemRepository`. Given I now have 2 repositories accessing the same database table, is that generally considered poor design? My thinking is, sometimes a user wants to update the details about an Item (e.g. name), but when using the `OrdersRepository`, it doesn't really make sense to not be able to access the items directly (you want to know about all the items in an order)

Of course, the `OrderRepository` could internally create* an `ItemRepository` and call methods like `getItemsById(ids: string[])`. However, consider the case that I want to get all orders and items ever purchased by a Customer. Assuming you had the orderIds for a customer, you could have a getOrders(ids: string[]) on the `OrderRepository` to fetch all the orders and then do a second query to fetch all the Items. I feel you make your life harder (and less efficient) in the sense you have to do the join to match items with orders in the app code rather than doing a join in SQL.

If it's not considered bad practice, is there some kind of limit to how much overlap Repositories should have with each other. I've spent a while trying to search for this on the web, but it seems all the tutorials/blogs/vdieos really don't go further than 1 table per entity (which may be an anti-pattern).

Or am I missing a trick?

Thanks

FYI: using express with TypeScript (not C#)

- is a repository creating another repository considered acceptable. shouldn't only the service layer do that?

Comment: "Given I now have 2 repositories accessing the same database table, is that generally considered poor design?"  It might mean that your data model could be improved.  Each field in your database should be subject to the authority of one and only one aggregate; so the question arises - why aren't the fields in separate tables?  What are the trade offs you are making, and are they the right ones?  Of course, sometimes the thing we absolutely have to have is legacy compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To confirm you are saying each field in the tables should only be touched (be it created, updated, read, destroyed) by one aggregate? Using my Customer, Order, Items scenario how would you model that to achieve what you're recommending?

Comment: Migrate the database to a schema where all of the fields in each table are subject to a single business authority.  Use joins and views when we need to combine information from multiple tables into a single report.  Note that a single authority might store its information in multiple tables -- that's fine -- and in some situations might cache its own copy of some other authority's data.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason
Not sure what is meant by business authority google isn't helping. Assuming business authority means aggregate:
Suppose I have a table, Orders. All but one field in that table (a field indicating if this order is still active) is owned by one aggregate. This single field is owned by another aggregate (which happens to be an authority on other fields in different tables).

If I want to delete a row in this table, then 2 aggregates would be affected. Is this likely a poor design and in reality there should only be one aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to separate the Database Model from the DDD design but you have to.

In your example:
GetItems should have this signature - `OrderRepostiory.GetItems(Ids: int[]) : ItemEntity`. Note that this method returns an Entity (not a DAO from your ORM). To get the ItemEntity, the method might pull information from several DAOs (tables, through your ORM) but it should only pull what it needs for the entity's hydration.

Say you want to update an item's name using the ItemRepository, your signature for that could look like `ItemRepository.rename(Id: int, name: string) : void`. When this method does it's work, it could change the same table as the GetItems above but note that it could also change other tables as well (For example, it could add an audit of the change to an AuditTable).

DDD gives you the ability to use different tables for different Contexts if you want. It gives you enough flexibility to make really bold choices when it comes the infrastructure that surrounds your domain. So ultimately, it's a matter of what makes sense for your specific situation and team. Some teams would apply CQRS and the GETOrder and Rename methods will look completely different under the covers.

Comment: just to confirm, in your example above, you have 2 different repositories touching the same table. That is generally consider OK, and often desirable?

Comment: Desirability depends on the usecase. Most usecases are OK with this strategy. An example of a usecase that might require something different is if: you need fast Reads (or fast writes), you might want to do something different.